# I am migrating from apollo-link-state to @apollo/client, how do I write default data to InMemoryCache of @apollo/client without using cache.writeData?

Tags: javascript, apollo, browser-cache, react-apollo, apollo-client

I use react 16.13 and am currently migrating from `apollo-client` 2.x to `@apollo/client` 3.1.1. I removed a lot of dependency libraries from my `packages.json` because most of them are now directly importable from `@apollo/client`. Everything was going fine until I tossed a big rock named "removal of defaults" while migrating from `apollo-link-state`.

With `@apollo/client` 3.x, we import `InMemoryCache` from `@apollo/client` directly, which is fine. But the `withClientState` link is no longer existent and `ApolloClient` doesn't support default values for local cache. I could not find any guide covering this problem. [There is one guide for Angular](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/local-state/#migrating-from-apollo-link-state), but it advises to use `cache.writeData` to construct the cache. Only problem is, in v3.x of `@apollo/client`, `InMemoryCache` doesn't have a `writeData` method anymore. There is a `modify` method but it is also not straightforward to use, at least I was not able to make it work for this purpose.

I have a large "defaults" object:

```
export default {
  authentication: {
    __typename: 'authentication',
    auth: ''
  },
  UserInfo: {
    __typename: 'UserInfo',
    employee: {
      __typename: 'UserInfoEmployee',
      defaultShopId: '',
      id: '',
      email: '',
      image: {
      __typename: 'image',
      id: '',
      url: ''
    },
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    manager: '',
    boss: ''
    },
    countryCode: '',
    chainId: ''
  },
  defaultShop: {
    __typename: 'defaultShop',
    id: '',
    name: '',
    timeZone: null
  },
  locale: {
    __typename: 'locale',
    locale: getBrowserLocale()
  },
  countries: {
    __typename: 'countries',
    data: []
  },
  Products: {
    __typename: 'Products',
    guid: 0,
    ProductTypes: {
      __typename: 'ProductTypes',
      TypeNumber: 0,
      type: ''
    },
    legacyConfiguration: false,
    version: '1.0.0'
  },
  location: {
    __typename: 'location',
    pathname: '',
    search: '',
    hash: null,
    action: '',
    key: null,
    isQueryActive: false,
    query: null
  }
}
```

How should I write these default data into `InMemoryCache` without using `cache.writeData`?

Comment: Try using `writeQuery`. You will need a query for your `defaults` shape. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.writeQuery

Comment: @UjinT34 thank you, I believe this is the only viable solution. I have solved the problem by executing a query for my defaults shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `writeQuery` instead.
I believe in v3 they moved towards using a common way for setting a default state.

[Official docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.writeQuery)

```
    const query = gql`
        query {
            authentication @client {
                id
                __typename
            }
            ...
        }`
    cache.writeQuery({
        query,
        data: {
            authentication: {
                __typename: 'authentication'
               ...
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be written using policies, cache.writeQuery didn't work for me at the time of initialization,

```
 cache.policies.addTypePolicies({
    Query: {
      fields: {
        selectedCurrency: {
          read() {
            return "USD";
          },
        },
        selectedIndex: {
          read() {
            return 0;
          },
        },
        bookingFlowStep: {
          read() {
            return '';
          },
        },
        
      },
    },
  });
```